# Group within case statement

Tags: sql, count, case, aggregate

I am trying to count all employees that were scheduled only to show up on sat/sun but actually showed up on other days apart from sat/sun.
I am trying to group this count by contractor_firm but I get an error on my case saying window functions not allowed.

```
  count(case
           when 
           TO_CHAR(emp_expected_date , 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') IN ('SAT', 'SUN') 
           and TO_CHAR(emp_actual_date , 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
           NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN') THEN emp_id OVER (PARTITION BY contractor)  ELSE NULL end)
           AS contractor_non_compliance
```

Comment: without the over won't it just give me an overall count. I need to group it by contractor ?

Comment: Well, you wrote *trying to group this count by contractor_firm*, this translates to `GROUP BY contractor`

Answer (score 0):

The part before `OVER` must be an aggregate, which is not the case in your query (you are aggregating the whole expression). So this is invalid SQL.

Maybe you wanted to do something like this:

```
count(case when ... then 1 end) OVER (PARTITION BY contractor)
```

Comment: Could you give some feed-back on the answers given?

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
sum(case when TO_CHAR(emp_expected_date , 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') IN ('SAT', 'SUN') and
              TO_CHAR(emp_actual_date , 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
         then 1 else 0
     end) as contractor_non_compliance
```

If you want the count of *employees* rather than incidents, then use `count(distinct)`:

```
count(distinct case when TO_CHAR(emp_expected_date , 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') IN ('SAT', 'SUN') and
                         TO_CHAR(emp_actual_date , 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
                    then emp_id
      end) as contractor_non_compliance
```

Answer (score 0):

There are likely a lot of better ways to achieve this, but here is one that should be close to working, without knowing your exact table structure:

```
SELECT count(emp_id), contractor_firm
FROM   your_table
WHERE  emp_id in (
    SELECT emp_id
    FROM   your_table
    WHERE  TO_CHAR(emp_expected_date,'DY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') in ('SAT','SUN')
    AND    TO_CHAR(emp_expected_date,'DY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') not in ('MON','TUES','WEDS','THURS','FRI')
    AND    TO_CHAR(emp_actual_date,'DY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') in ('MON','TUES','WEDS','THURS','FRI')
)
GROUP BY contractor_firm
```

This will `COUNT()` only the `emp_ids` that were scheduled to work on *either* 'Sat' or 'Sun', not any weekdays, then ended up working on one of the weekdays.  I stress *either* here because they did not necessarily have to be scheduled on both 'Sat' and 'Sun' - I believe this corresponds with your requirements.